# Comparing calendar objects

Tags: java, calendar, compare

I'm having some trouble with comparing 2 calendar objects. Here's my code:

```
String date = "06/19/2015";

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            String days="", months="", years="";
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(date);
            sc.useDelimiter("/");
            while(sc.hasNext()){
                months = sc.next();
                days = sc.next();
                years = sc.next();
            }
            int day = Integer.parseInt(days);
            int month = Integer.parseInt(months);
            int year = Integer.parseInt(years);
            System.out.println(day+" "+month+" "+year);

            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
            cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
            cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);

if(c.before(cal)){
   System.out.println("Victory!");
}

            sc.close();
```

It should compare today's date with the date from the string and print out 'Vicotry!'. Problem is, it's always printing it out, even when it shouldnt... Could someone help me?

Comment: On a side note there is a simpler method to parsing a date string (i.e. SimpleDateFormat).

Comment: But that woulndt give me seperate ints for day, month, year to set the time with in 'cal', right?

Comment: It does. You use the SimpleDateFormat to get a Date object and you call setTime on the calender with the date object.

Comment: I see, I'll try that out right away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  problem is **you set the calendar months the wrong way**, you should be using the Calendar constants or be aware of the internal workings if you are gonna set the fields manually.

You treat june like the integer value 6 , however the callendar's months are indexed 0 to 11 so Calendar.JUNE will be 5, not 6. Your manual date parsing solution sets the month of the `Calendar cal` to July (`Calendar.JULY` is 6)

---

I suggest a cleaner approach, by parsing the date with a `DateFormat`. You don't really neet to use the `Calendar` to get the current date. Better to use `new Date()` instead of `Calendar.getInstance()`.

If you do want to process a date's fields you can use `calendarObj.setTime(dateObject)`.

```
    String dateString = "06/19/2015";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    try {
        Date date1 = sdf.parse(dateString);
        //makes sense using calendar only if you want to process the date fields
        //otherwise use if (new Date().before(date1)){...}
        if (c.getTime().before(date1)) {
            System.out.println("Victory!");
        };

        date1.getTime();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid date format");
    }
```